# Python Slope (given two points find the slope) -answer works & doesn't work;

Tags: python, function, line

Trying to figure out the function to return the slope of a line in Python. Problem directions are to find the slope of m with the slope coordinates given. Read through several other stack overflow posts, but none seem to make a working solution. Here are a variety of the variations I've tried:

```
def slope(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    m = 0
    b = (x2 - x1)
    d = (y2 - y1)
    if b != 0:
        m = (d)/(b) 

    return m

slope(2, 3, 6, 7)


def slope(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    m = 0
    a = float(x1)
    b = float(x2)
    c = float(y1)
    d = float(y2)
    m = (d-c)/(b-a)
    return m
slope(2, 3, 6, 7)

def slope(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    m = ''
    a = float(x1)
    b = float(x2)
    c = float(y1)
    d = float(y2)
    m = (d-c)/(b-a)
    return m

slope(2, 3, 6, 7)



def slope(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    m = 0
    b = (x2 - x1)
    d = (y2 - y1)
    if b == 0:

        m = None

    else: 

        m = (d)/(b) 

    return m


slope(2, 3, 6, 7)

def slope(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
    return m

slope(2, 3, 6, 7)
```

At one point, I received error messages regarding a global m. I also tried making a " m = 0 " outside the function, but that didn't help. Also received `"AssertionError: 0 != 1"`

I've gotten the right answer followed by a second line =>None and when submitting the system says that it is not correct.

Comment: Your last function worked just fine for me (actually, all of them worked, but that one is my favorite out of all the ones you've written), and returned a slope of 1.  Are you having trouble seeing the result?  Simply call `print slope(2, 3, 6, 7)` and it will print out the returned value for you.

Comment: Thanks for checking it. Realized they didn't want a function submitted. It was printing and showing "1" for the answer, but the system I was submitting to didn't accept it (like when you submit working code to Codecademy, but it's not written in the function they pre-determine as right).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your math is spot on, so that's not the problem.  I tested all of your functions by adding `print` statements, and they all correctly returned `1.0`.

Does your system require that you print out the returned value?  Do this.

```
def slope(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
    return m

print slope(2, 3, 6, 7)
```

You can even optimize a bit more by leaving out the variable and directly returning your calculation, like this:

```
def slope(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
```

Comment: Thank you! I realized they didn't want a function submitted to the system...(palm to face on that one haha)

Comment: I just want do add that you should be careful dividing by `x2 - x1`. If this equals to 0, you would divide by 0 which is not possible. I suggest adding `if x2 - x1 == 0: return 1e12` or any large or ideally infinite number.